# How does a virtual user differ from a user authenticated using a custom membership provider?

Tags: authentication, federated-authentication, user-management

Just wondering, what is the difference between a Sitecore virtual user and a user authenticated using a custom membership provider(and respective custom profile and role provider)?

I have been implementing federated authentication in Sitecore 6.6 application, once claims are received, I'm unable to get user authenticated to Sitecore using custom membership provider implementation (as it is implemented when the application is built to authenticate against an active directory).

It has been advised to authenticate by building virtual Sitecore users, in federated authentication scenarios and why not using custom membership providers.